# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'ControlCollection'

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am designing a windows application using C#, I have created dynamically 2 Textboxes, 5 Comboboxes and 1 NumericUpDown. I want all their values to be saved in database using 3-tier architecture, but i came across a unresolved frustrating issue. I have used Control Collection so that i can go through value of each control. Am I right with this approach?. Secondly when i tried to get the value of my Textbox in a Message Box it throws an exception of "Unable to cast an object of 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'ControlCollection' My code:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(this.Controls);
foreach (ControlCollection ctrl in list)
{
    if(ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ctrl[2].Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `foreach (var txt in Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) MessageBox.Show(txt.Text);`

Comment: I think your iterator variable is wrong? ControlCollection is collection of controls rather than control itself...

Comment: It is showing me text of both textboxes I want the text of each textbox to be shown separately when called like with the help of index or other references , this was the reason why i have used ControlCollection but I came across with this exception furthermore I am not sure whether it is right or not.

Comment: You shouldn't copy "this.Controls" like that. You should iterate over it directly. If you use a collection use a generic one to save yourself some headaches: List<Control> list for example.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with lists can you please provide me code for it. Any namespace required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below tested and working sample code

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = "aa";
        tb.Text = "11";

        TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
        tb2.Name = "bb";
        tb2.Text = "22";
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
        this.Controls.Add(tb2);

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                if (c.Name.Equals("bb")) 
                    MessageBox.Show("bb value:" + c.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have used the same code before but it grabbed the value of both textboxes but i only want to see the value of called textbox like with the help of indexing or other reference. I have also tried to use keys with controls but at that point it throws me null value exception :(

Comment: what you mean by called textbox?

Comment: i mean specific textbox. I have two textboxes 1 for rate and 2 for total cost. Suppose i only want to see rate but it is showing me total cost also

Comment: can't you get the text by using control.Text property?

Comment: They are dynamically generated how can i use their names??

Comment: No, I am getting text of both of them with a single .Text call. I have to save them separately in database so how can i separate them that's my big issue

Comment: when you adding control you can give a name, then check for that name inside the loop

Comment: I have also done this it provides me name of other controls in message box but the one i have generated dynamically it gives me blank message box

Comment: @user3652368 How are you distinguishing between the textboxes you create dynamically

Comment: Thats the main problem I am unable to distinguishing between them. When I call  .Text method it returns me values of both textboxes. So far I tried to use indexing but with this approach it returns me with the exception mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Damith Thank you sir thank you very very much. In my running confusion i even did not notice your edited post. It is working feeling relaaaaxxxxeeeeddddd now. :)